# Getting a JSON error after importing react-bootsrap components into FB Create-React-App Boilerplate

Tags: facebook, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am simply trying to understand react components.

I know I am doing something wrong but I dont know what.

I am just trying to get a navbar component to show up on the test page of the Create-React-App Boilerplate.

Here is my Package JSON:

```
 {
  "name": "Test_WebSite",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.8.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  }
  // ...
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
}
```

Here is my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

const MenuBar =({name, Link1, Link2})=>(

<Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
  <Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Brand>
      <a href="#">{name}</a>
    </Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle />
  </Navbar.Header>
  <Navbar.Collapse>
    <Nav>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">{Link1}</NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">{Link2}</NavItem>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
);



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <div>
          <MenuBar name="WTF"/>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

After adding `import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap'`and creating the Menubar Component I get this error:

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/App.js
Module not found: Syntax/Volumes/Main Drive/Test_WebSite/package.json (directory description file): SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 411

 @ ./src/App.js 21:22-48
```

I dont think it is JSON related though because if I remove everything I added the test page renders correctly.

I have no doubt it is something simple but I ca not see it.  Any help would greatly be appresated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got it to work:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' //<< added this css file
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

const MenuBar =({Name, Link1, Link2})=>(
<Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
  <Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Brand>
      <a href="#">{Name}</a>
    </Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle />
  </Navbar.Header>
  <Navbar.Collapse>
    <Nav>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">{Link1}</NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">{Link2}</NavItem>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
);


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <div>
          <MenuBar Name="Am I a Fool" Link1="Foo" Link2="Bar" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to resolve `Link1`, `Link2` from `props` in your `MenuBar` component  which are just not there. Try passing these props to the `MenuBar` component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

const MenuBar =({name, Link1, Link2})=>(

<Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
  <Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Brand>
      <a href="#">{name}</a>
    </Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle />
  </Navbar.Header>
  <Navbar.Collapse>
    <Nav>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">{Link1}</NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">{Link2}</NavItem>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
);



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <div>
          <MenuBar name="WTF" Link1="abc" Link2="xyz"/>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Package.json

```
 {
  "name": "Test_WebSite",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.8.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
   // }                     <<<<<<< Extra Curly brace was here causing an issue
  // ...
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },           <<<<<<<<<< dont need a comman here as this is the last entry, remove it.
}
```

Comment: @DT90 I think you have an extra `}` in youir package.json which might be the syntax error causing this issue

Comment: Does the error change or you get the same error. Also check for any other syntax erros in package.json

Comment: It is really frustration. If I remove everything it renders but as soon as I add anything react-bootstrap related I get the JSON error

Comment: removing the braces did not make a difference

Comment: I  solved the problem. I npm bootstrap as well as react-bootstrap. I imported bootstraps css and that seems to have solved the issue

Comment: Okay nice, but you might have made the changes I suggested in my answer too